# What could be the reason for .slideToggle() to work when .slideUp() and slideDown() doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Background:**

I ran into a problem that I find somewhat unexpected. I have a small jQuery module where I've been using `.slideToggle()` to show/hide an element and it has been working fine. Today I'm implementing two public methods for my plugin, to either show or hide the element with a sliding effect.

Simple as it sounds, I though I'd just use `.slideUp()` and `slideDown()` to accomplish the same thing. I was really surprised when I realized that nothing happened upon calling those methods on the element.

*As a side note, calling `.show()` and `.hide()` works fine as well, but without the desired animation off course.*

I always thought that `.slideToggle()` implemented the same functionality as `.slideUp()` and `.slideDown()` "under the hood", but apparently it doesn't.

**My question:**

In what way does `.slideToggle()` differ from `.slideUp()` and `.slideDown()` and what do I have to consider when using one compared to the others?

**Update, example:**

I've been able to break it down into the most crucial components needed to reproduce this error in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Krz5/2/). You can comment out `.slideToggle("slow")` and `.slideUp("slow")` respectively to test it. With slideToggle it works, with slideUp it doesnt.

Comment: Show the actual code that has the problem!

Comment: @epascarello I'll try to break it down to the essentials in a Fiddle, but it is part of a rather large set of CSS and JS. I thought that there might be some obvious difference between `.slideToggle()` and `.slideUp()`, due to implementation differences, that could explain this.

Comment: @Christofer, `slideToggle()` is not implemented in terms of `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` (the three methods are actually implemented in terms of `animate()`). Are you perchance forcing the element's height to some value in CSS?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Allright, thanks for the insight on that. I'm not forcing the elements height in any way, but it is contained in a parent element that has a fixed positioning at the bottom of the window, if that can affect it in any way? (I haven't set the `top` property though, so it shouldn't force any height on the parent either).

Comment: @Christofer, I would double-check the calls to `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` then. Are you sure you're not calling `slideUp()` when the element is hidden and `slideDown()` when it is visible, instead of the other way around?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Unfortunately not, I've called it straight from the console in the browser as well just to be sure, but with the same result. I can select the element, but `.slideUp()` has no effect.

Comment: @epascarello I've update the question with a fiddle that demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi You were absolutely right, the problem was me mixing up the methods. See the accepted answer. If you put it as an answer, I'd be happy to accept yours as the correct answer instead, since you were the first to post it. Many thanks for your help anyways!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `slideUp` is not the best name for the method. A better name would be "slideHide". If you change it to `slideDown` it works as expected, since that corresponds to show.

From http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

> Description: Hide the matched elements with a sliding motion.

Comment: Man, do I feel stupid now! I got so stuck in my mind that I wan't to use slideUp(), because the header should move upwards, that I missed the obvious. Thank you!

Comment: If that isn't posted as a ticket on jQuery's github repo, you should really add it as a suggestion. `.slideHide()` is obviously a much better name.

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson It would make more sense to be renamed to `slideIn` and `slideOut` to match `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`.

Answer (score 1):

It in fact works the same way. I believe you have reversed the order in which to call `slideDown` and `slideUp`. Here is an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Krz5/4/).

Code:

```
var flip = true;
$(".dockedHeader").on("click", function () {
    if (flip) {
        $(".content").slideDown("slow");
        flip = !flip;
    } else {
        $(".content").slideUp("slow");
        flip = !flip;
    }
    //$(".content").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Initially your content is hidden so you should call `sliderDown()` instead of `slideUp()` to show it and vice versa.

Comment: This is quite embarrassing, I got so hung up on the name slideUp because it looks like the element is sliding upwards. I've chosen to accept Tetaxas answer, because he really put my confusion into words, but thanks a lot for your help!